# What's the name for the local change in area/volume/measure?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, terminology, change-of-variable

Suppose $f : A \rightarrow B$ is a continuous function between locally compact topological spaces equipped with regular measures, lets call them $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$. Lets also assume that $\mu_A$ has empty support. Then for each $a \in A$, we can study what $f$ does to the measure of a little neighborhood of $a$. To ensure the image of such a neighbourhood is measurable, lets focus just on the compact neighbourhoods. In particular, we can study the net $f[a] : \mathrm{CompactNbhd}(a) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $$f[a](N) = \frac{\mu_B(f(N))}{\mu_A(N)}.$$ The numerator makes sense because $f(N)$ is compact, hence closed, hence Borel. The denominator is non-zero because the $\mu_A$ has non-empty support. If this net converges, presumably this tells us something important about what $f$ is doing to the measures of things near $a$. For example, if $A$ and $B$ are Euclidean spaces of equal dimension, it should be the case that this number converges to $|\mathrm{det} Jf_a|$, where $J$ is the Jacobian. I guess something similar can be probably be said if $A$ and $B$ are Riemannian manifolds.

> **Question.** When it exists, what is this number called?

Comment: There is the concept of taking the so called Radon-Nikodym derivative (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) of a measure with respect to another measure -- is this what you have in mind?

Comment: @Thomas, I don't think they're the same. We could try taking the pushforward measure $f_*(\mu_A)$ and then taking a Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to $\mu_B$, for example, but this would give us a function on $B$. The definition in my question actually gives a function on $A$, when it exists.

Comment: I'm not aware of a good conventional term for this - perhaps "volume dilation"? In Riemannian geometry it's typically just called the Jacobian determinant.